# window.clipboardData.getData("Text") returns 0 in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, clipboard

I'm trying to implement maxlength on a textarea.  In IE7, `window.clipboardData.getData("Text")` returns the correct number of characters copied. in IE8, the same call returns 0. What's wrong?

here is the js

```
var someRule= {
  "textarea" : function(element) {
    element.onpaste = function() {
      var copied = window.clipboardData.getData("Text");
      alert('copied length = '+copied.length);
    }
  }
};

Behaviour.register(someRule);
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a security setting in IE8:

To prevent a web site from reading your clipboard, take the following steps:

Go to Tools->Internet Options. 
Click on the Security Tab. 
Click on "Custom Level." 
Scroll down to the Scripting section under Settings. 
Set "Allow paste operations via script" to Disable or Prompt. 
Press the OK buttons to close the dialog boxes.

In your case, this setting is probably disabled.

Comment: I don't have rights to change these settings :(.  But I did not know that, thanks for the suggestion. Any other ideas?

Comment: These instructions were how to disable this security setting. To have the script access the clipboard, the setting would need to be enabled. If you don't have permission to change these settings, the script will not be allowed to access the clipboard.

Comment: I've been using a stock test machine with a base image with IE8 (I'm on IE7 until 8 is pushed out to everyone).  I tried my code on a fellow devs machine and it worked.  Must be a Group Policy or OU setting. Thanks!